# Edit Custom Attribute after Log In

Tags: authentication, liferay, hook, liferay-6

I can only Edit a custom field when I before edit it by hand with the user administrator.

What's wrong with my code and what I should do to solve this??

Exactly, I'm trying to assign a value to a User custom attribute when It logs in the portal. And I'm not able to get ExpandoColumn in the conditions specified.

**The problem is that ExpandoValue is null.**

```
 public class LoginAction extends Action {

        public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
            User currentUser;
            try {
                currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser(req);
                long userId = PrincipalThreadLocal.getUserId();
                long companyId = currentUser.getCompanyId();            
                long groupId = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(companyId, "Guest").getGroupId();

                /* Get de CustomField Segmentation */
                ExpandoTable expandoTable = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultTable(companyId, User.class.getName());

                ExpandoColumn expandoColumn = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.getColumn(companyId, User.class.getName(), expandoTable.getName(), "Segmentation");           


          if (expandoColumn != null) {
                 ExpandoValue expandoValue = ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(expandoTable.getTableId(), expandoColumn.getColumnId(), userId);

          if (expandoValue != null) {
                 expandoValue.setData(finalsegment);


                 ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.updateExpandoValue(expandoValue);

          }
   }
```

}

**Summary:** My problem is that

`ExpandoValue expandoValue = ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(expandoTable.getTableId(), expandoColumn.getColumnId(), classPK);`

is Null when I access the Value of Custom Attribute. If I edit by hand this customattribute and then execute the same Code it works!!! I don't know why and I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the answer of the question..

You can manage the solution with the code proposed.

http://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26154530

Answer (score 1):

Edit (after your update to the question)

Take a look at the [ExpandoValueLocalService javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/expando/service/ExpandoValueLocalService.html#createExpandoValue%28long%29): You'll find that there's a `createExpandoValue` method. Now guess the relationship between the scenario "You have not manually set the value at all, and you're getting back `null` as ExpandoValue" vs. "You have set it once and get back a value that you can update...

Another option would also be to just specify a default value for your expando value - this way you'll definitely have a value in there and you can unconditionally update it (at least until it's deliberately deleted - for robustness you should still cater for this possibility)

Original answer:

Where else but in the `if` condition do you go? Have you tried an `else` condition or do you get any exception before? E.g. you might need to create the 'default' table before you can just get it.

See [this code](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-podcasting-hook/blob/master/docroot/WEB-INF/src/de/olafkock/liferay/blogs/ExtBlogUtil.java) for an example on how to access Expando Tables/Columns.

I didn't run your code, but of course exceptions might occur earlier as well. Or you might have made a mistake in configuring your `LoginAction`, so that it doesn't run at all.

Comment: I update the question: My problem is that "ExpandoValue expandoValue = ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(expandoTable.getTableId(), expandoColumn.getColumnId(), classPK);"  is Null when I access the Value of Custom Attribute. If I edit by hand this customattribute and then try the same it functions!!!

Comment: I tried this solution!!! The problem is that I cannot find or generate a free valueId. Do you know how I can find one?? And.. I already specified a default value for the expando value without succeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, regular User role has no permissions to access Expando values.

Anyway, it is better to modify expando values with

```
User user = UserLocalService.getUserById(userId);
user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
```

If you want to modify value with any permissions, use

```
user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue", false);
```